# Error posting a tweet via python TwitterAPI

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to post a tweet via TwitterApi, using oAuth2 and I get error

```
'u'{"errors":[{"code":220,"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."}]}'
```

My code is as follows:
    from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

```
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xyz'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xyz'

def tweet_it():
    api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, auth_type='oAuth2')
    r = api.request('statuses/update', {'status': 'Hello World!'})
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tweet_it()
```

I have set my app account permissions to 'Read, Write and Access direct messages' and regenerate consumer keys. What am I missing?

I could search tweets this way without any issues.

I could post and search using oAuth1.

Comment: How much time have you allowed after giving the proper permission?

Comment: It's already couple of hours after I've changed permissions. Btw I've had read/write even before. I only haven't had 'access direct messages'

Comment: Yea that can't be the case, 220 is an API permission problem not a credentials otherwise you'll get 401. I think it may have something to do with the way you're initializing the oauth. It's strange that's happening only for updating the status tho. Check last block see if it helps [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only)

Comment: I've found out solution, or better say what's an issue here. I will answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the solution or better say what is the issues.

Behavior described in my questions is correct as I'm using *Application-only authentication* and with this it's not allowed to access certain API calls, see https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only.

Following twitter api documentation

- for calling my account only, it's best way to go with oAuth1 and specify consumer key and access token and corresponding secrets.
- for calling it from 3rd party application, you should go with 3-legged authorization, see https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged.